# Audio Designer vs  Sound Designer

Tags: designer

Hello

May be a stupid question (sorry for that), but which is the difference between an audio designer and a sound designer ? Or it's the same job ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially Audio and Sound Designer are interchangeable jobs in the games industry, it just depends upon which company you are working for.

In more general terms audio refers to the electrical/digital sound signal and sound refers to the physical vibrations through a medium like air or water.

Answer (score 1):

I have blogged on the difference between Sound Design and Sound Engineering (http://sound-sculpting.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-is-sound-design-different-to-sound.html), but your question is slightly different to this.  IMO Iain's distinction between Sound and Audio sums it up.